# Custom wordpress gallery

Tags: html, wordpress, gallery

The typical code of wordpress gallery is `<div withmanyclass><dl class><dt class><a href=""><img class>`
(see below)

This is the original code wordpress uses:

```
<div id="gallery-2" class="gallery galleryid-16 gallery-columns-5 gallery-size-thumbnail"><dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <a href="link1.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1903913040" data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="16_auto_1"><img width="150" height="150" src="name1.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt=""></a>
    </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <a href="link2.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="72767957" data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="16_auto_1"><img width="150" height="150" src="name2.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt=""></a>
    </dt></dl 

    <br style="clear: both">
</div>
```

How do I convert it into other simple code with custom classes? (via functions.php)

```
<div class="mini-gallery-wrapper">
    <a data-lightbox="image-1" href="img/sample1.jpg" data-title="Przykład" class="mini-gallery-item">
        <img src="img/sample1small.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a data-lightbox="image-2" href="img/sample2.jpg" data-title="Przykład" class="mini-gallery-item">
        <img src="img/sample2small.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```